# Android Virtual Device is not showing the output?

Tags: android

My simple android to print hello world is not running properly. Android virtual Device is getting start but not showing any output. Here is my code plz fix it.

its my java class.

```
package com.example.jack;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

here is mainActivity.xml for layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is String.xmm.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">jack</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello World</string>

</resources>
```

here is AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.jack"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.jack.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Avd is showing only the android image. Nothing more.. Plz help me out.

Comment: Did it work on a physical device?

Comment: did you close the `<LinearLayout>` tag or is just copy paste error?

Comment: and also strings.xml... </resources>

Comment: @ArtooDetoo yes its a copy paste error. I have closed them properly.

Comment: @aoeu I did't test it on a physical device.

Comment: Would you add the `AndroidManifest.xml` code

Comment: @RocketSpock now I have add the Manifest file.

Comment: @user3320609 can you attach logs    .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVD showing only the android image and nothing else loading after a reasonable period of time likely means that your system is unable to render the resolution that you have chosen (Note that I said most likely - in some cases, I have found that AVD takes like 15 minutes just to start but then runs properly after that). A solution to this would be to check the 'Use Host GPU' option under Emulation options.

If that does not solve it, try to reduce the Memory and VM heap options. That should most certainly solve it.

If you are unable to start the app on a physical device as well, then it likely means there is an error in your app.

Answer (score 0):

The AVD can take a while to start up the first time depending on the machine resources and does stay on the Android Logo for some time. It should always boot up completely through. If there is an error with your app it will show you an alert saying your app has stopped working. Just give it some time to boot completely.